# need to convert date and compare it in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time

ExpressionEngine stores dates as int (shaking head at this) in the database

For example: 1382049076 = 2013-10-17

I am looking to return records that have an entry_date between a start and end date

I tried using but that does not work, when I remove this from the WHERE part of the query, it retrieves records, I feel like I am close.

```
DATE_CONVERT('entry_date', '%Y-%m-%d') >= $start_date and DATE_CONVERT('entry_date', '%Y-%m-%d') <= $end_date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `entry_date` is an integer column in your table, here's the a useful way to select rows based on date.

```
 SELECT whatever
   FROM table
  WHERE entry_date >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP($start_date)
    AND entry_date < UNIX_TIMESTAMP($end_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Three little details here make this query work well.

One: your $start_date and $end_date strings need to be formatted 'YYYY-MM-DD' for this to work.

Two: timestamps can be in the middle of days. But the timestamp of a date without a time is the timestamp of the first second of that day (that is, midnight).  Hence the `<` (not `<=`) and the monkey business with `+ INTERVAL 1 DAY` for the end of the date range. It's asking for any timestamp strictly less than midnight on the day after the end of your date range.

Three:  this query doesn't apply any functions to `entry_date`. That's good because it allows the use of an index, and a range scan, to identify the rows that are within date range.

Answer (score 2):

You have got a UNIX timestamp, so you must use `from_unixtime` function, for example:

```
SELECT *
  FROM table
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`entry_date`), '%Y-%m-%d') >= $start_date
   AND DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`entry_date`), '%Y-%m-%d') <= $end_date
```

Comment: Unfortunately this will defeat the use of any index on `entry_date`, not a desirable outcome.

Answer (score 1):

Your `1382049076` is a simple unix timestamp. You can use it directly in mysql:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(entry_date), ...
```

which would return `2013-10-17 14:31:16` (at least it does in my UTC-6 timezone).